# scdf 1.7.3 docker k8s function-runner not start

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Trying to deploy into scdf k8s a function-runner into a stream

```
http --server.port=9001 | f-run: function-runner --function.className=com.example.functions.CharCounter --class-name=com.example.functions.CharCounter --location="maven://io.spring.sample:function-sample:jar:1.0.2" | log
```

I've create a docker image using `function-runner-kafka 1.1.0.M1`.

Always get :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Binding to target org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.function.app.FunctionProperties@264f218 failed:
    Property: function.className
    Value: null
    Reason: may not be empty
Action:
Update your application's configuration
```

Into stream definition, how can i set the `maven` uri to the `function-jar`?

I wanna run function-runner with jar code into a scdf k8s

Answer (score 0):

The `function-runner` model is deprecated in favor of native Spring Cloud Function integration available in Spring Cloud Stream.

You can simply build a Spring Cloud Stream application with just function `@Bean`'s and have them part of the functional flow as a chain or resolved as an individual function at runtime.

See [ref. guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_function) for more details.

Once when you have an application with multiple function `@Bean`'s, you also have the ability to compose them with other App Starters and use it in the SCDF DSL, too.

Refer to this [blog on this subject](https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/09/composed-function-support-in-spring-cloud-data-flow) for more background.

Comment: I am sorry. I have open a new post because i didnt write into another one. Locked. I don't write into stackoverflow usually and today i only have mobile phone to use. Please be patient, i don't work in pivotal and i need your help. how can i write <intro>

Comment: I forget function runner. I was trying your dok references and i can't get it work. I cannot change from use Spring 1.x because we got a Lot of connectors code inthis  version. But, using @bean for simple processor i can't work.It is deployed ok un k8s but no messages from time to function processor. Why? Any logs can i enable?. I am learning scdf and function, i think i don't need composite function if i can't do run i simply processor function. I think i have copies Spring function processor from 1.x and test with@functionscan, with params deployed..

Comment: The problem here is that you're on an ancient Boot version and to top all that, we do not recommend the use of `function-runner` app anymore. We never released a GA version of this app for the same reason - it was meant to be experimentation. Instead of using this app, download a new Spring Boot app, and declare the `@Bean` definition similar to samples in the SCSt docs above. Build that app and test it locally via `java -jar`. You can choose between a source, processor, or a sink for your sample test. Start small and try to make it work locally on the laptop before using SCDF or K8s.