# scdf 1.7.3 docker k8s @Bean no running, no logs

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

As a user, writing a processor as a cloud function,
scdf 1.7.3, spring boot 1.5.9, spring-cloud-function-dependencies 1.0.2,

```
public class MyFunctionBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFunctionBootApp.class, 
        "--spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=toUpperCase");
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> toUpperCase() {
        return s -> {
            log.info("received:=" + s);
            return ( (s+"jsa").toUpperCase());
        };
    }
}
```

i've create a simple stream => time | function-runner | log 
function-runner-0.0.6.jar at nexus is ok
docker created ok, 
Container entrypoint set to [java, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*, function.runner.MyFunctionBootApp]

No time message from time pod arrived to function-runner processor executing toUpperCase function
No logs

I am checking deploying using , app.function-runner.spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=toUpperCase, @FunctionalScan

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

We discussed `function-runner` being deprecated in favor of native support of Spring Cloud Function in Spring Cloud Stream. See: [scdf-1-7-3-docker-k8s-function-runner-not-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455066/scdf-1-7-3-docker-k8s-function-runner-not-start). Please don't duplicate post it.

Also, you're on a very old Spring Boot version (v1.5.9 - [at least 1.5yrs old](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/28/spring-boot-1-5-9-available-now)). More importantly, Spring Boot 1.x is in maintenance-only mode, and it will be EOL by August 2019. See: [spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019). It'd be good that you upgrade to 2.1.x latest.